# Create role assignment in terraform based on region

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I am looking for a solution here on Terraform for creating role assignment and selecting the principal ids based on region..
If I am running the code to china, the variable should be "local.principal_ids_cn" and if global, then it has to be "local.principal_ids"..
I do have a env variable where the geo will be set based on cluster-name.. so "if geo = cn use local.principal_ids_cn, else use local.principal_ids"
How can this be incorporated in terraform?

This is my input file:

```
    "applications" : [
        {
            "principal_id" : "00000000-000000-global-000000000000", 
            "principal_id_cn" : "00000000-000000-china-000000000000",

        }
]
}
```

My resource block looks like this:

```
locals {
# get json
role_data = jsondecode(file(var.inputfile))
principal_ids = distinct([for principal in local.role_data.applications : principal.principal_id])
principal_ids_cn = distinct([for principal_cn in local.role_data.applications : principal.principal_id_cn])
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom" {
  for_each = toset(local.principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = var.custom_role
  principal_id = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin" {
  for_each = toset(local.principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
  principal_id = each.key
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "custom_role" {
  type = string
  description = "custom role"
  default = "READER"
}

variable "builtin_role" {
  type = string
  description = "builtin role"
  default = "My_built_in_role"
}
```

If there is a possibility to switch over the local variables based on the regions(china and global)?
Any suggestions ate ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: "If I am running the code to china" - how is that decided? Do you have some variable "which_region_I_am_running_for"?

Comment: Yes, I do have a env variable where the geo will be set based on cluster-name.. 
so "if geo = cn use local.principal_ids_cn, else use local.principal_ids"

Comment: You can use conditional expression and create new variable principal. Here is an example:  local.principal = (var.geo == "cn" ? local.principal_ids_cn :  local.principal_ids) https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html

Comment: @AndriyBilous that should go as the answer then.

Comment: Yeah.. that sounds a simple solutions.. Thanks for the hint.. Will give it a shot and update.. Thanks again.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. That worked like a charm.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional expression in Terraform to implement the logic "if geo = cn use local.principal_ids_cn, else use local.principal_ids"

Terraform code for your resource block:

```
locals {
# get json
  role_data = jsondecode(file(var.inputfile))
  principal_ids = distinct([for principal in local.role_data.applications : principal.principal_id])
  principal_ids_cn = distinct([for principal_cn in local.role_data.applications : principal.principal_id_cn])
  principal = (var.geo == "cn" ? local.principal_ids_cn : local.principal_ids)
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom" {
  for_each = toset(local.principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = var.custom_role
  principal_id = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin" {
  for_each = toset(local.principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
  role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
  principal_id = each.key
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html